# Why using custom Comparator to treeSet is breaking the equality of String objects?

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I have written a comparator which is calculating consonants in a given string to compare 2 strings, but it is somehow making TreeSet think that 2 strings are equal (may be when they are of same size).

```
public class SortDiff {
public static void main(String[] s1) {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("century", "army", "spit", "twin", "frog", "guideline", "impulse",
            "distributor", "hallway", "appeal", "fitness", "pudding", "mild", "enter", "kitchen", "constitutional",
            "die", "condition", "morsel", "jealous", "colorful", "myth", "belly", "rugby", "valid", "shot",
            "locate", "preference", "representative", "chart", "prince", "think", "threshold", "health", "sweater",
            "volume", "poison", "lease", "toast", "diplomat", "trait", "cower", "slime", "handy", "example",
            "sanctuary", "board", "crash", "large", "attract", "censorship", "room", "license", "smoke", "roll",
            "taste", "inflate", "continuation", "establish", "fault", "gown", "dirty", "width", "qualify",
            "reference", "excitement", "vegetable", "wear", "confusion", "concept", "willpower", "snarl", "develop",
            "integration", "pie", "respectable", "fast", "limit", "shaft", "acceptance", "insert", "brown", "death",
            "effective", "ticket", "play", "highway", "lot", "tablet", "mother", "pier", "facility", "match",
            "animal", "sport", "laundry", "negligence", "white", "vat", "nuclear");
    System.out.println(list.size() + "=====");
    TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>(new sortByConsonants());//
    int count = 0;
    for (String s : list) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(tree.add(s));
    }
    System.out.println("===>" + count);
    System.out.println(tree.size() + "=====");
    Iterator itr = tree.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}


}
```

This is the comparator class which I am passing to TreeSet.

```
class sortByConsonants implements Comparator<String>{

    public int compare(String a, String b) 
    { 

        return count(a,2)-count(b,2);
    } 
    public boolean equals(String a,String b) {

        return a.equals(b);

    }

    public int count(String line,int type) {
        int vowels = 0, consonants = 0, digits = 0, spaces = 0;

        line = line.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i)
        {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i'
                || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
                ++vowels;
            }
            else if((ch >= 'a'&& ch <= 'z')) {
                ++consonants;
            }
            else if( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                ++digits;
            }
            else if (ch ==' ')
            {
                ++spaces;
            }
        }

        if(type==1) {
            return vowels;
        }else {
            return consonants;
        }

    }

}
```

Can someone please look into it and find what mistake I am making!!

Goal : I want to sort strings based on count of consonants (Without use of library sort() method)

Edit : changed to comparator logic to

```
public int compare(String a, String b) 
    { 
        if(count(a,2)-count(b,2)==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return count(a,2)-count(b,2);
    }
```

Still not working!!

Edit =  For this question TreeSet is not the right Data Structure, should use ArrayList.

Comment: This looks wrong `if((ch >= 'a'&& ch <= 'z'))`, what if its a vowel again?

Comment: Well, when compare returns 0, the strings are equal (in the sense of this comperator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `SortByConsonants`  to the following. *(Note that class names should start with a capital letter)*

```
class SortByConsonants implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (count(a) - count(b) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return count(a) - count(b);
    }

    public boolean equals(String a, String b) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }

    public int count(String line) {
        int consonants = 0;
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if (ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u') {
                consonants++;
            }
        }
        return consonants;
    }

}
```

Also, since we are just interested to sort based on the *count* of consonants there is no need to calculate the number of vowels, spaces, digits, etc. Furthermore, there is also no need of passing in another parameter *type* to the method `count`

Comment: well, you actually fixed my broken count method, Kudos. Now the problem remains is that I need to sort the String Objects based on number of consonants. Could you please help me with that also?

Comment: I did , its returning 11 elements only ( all of different size);===>100
11=====
die
army
enter
appeal
century
colorful
guideline
preference
distributor
continuation
constitutional

Comment: Ah I see. Why even use a *TreeSet*? You could simply sort the list using : `list.sort(new sortByConsonants());` And now print it `list.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: I want to sort the strings without using sort method; Thats why I used this particular logic.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The reason they were getting omitted is because when the number of consonants are equal we aren't doing anything. Also there is no need to count the number of vowels, spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your comperator as you coded it, will return `0` (meaning equality) 
if 2 strings have **the same number of consonants**.
You defined:

```
TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>(new sortByConsonants());
```

so in `tree` there can't exist 2 items (strings) with the same number of consonants

Comment: Okays, seems my logic is flawed. Can you please help me achieve my goal (edited the question)

Comment: I understand that you want the items sorted by the number of consonants. But why use a Treeset? This restricts the items you store in it.

Comment: I thought Tree would keep the strings sorted based on the custom comparator logic I would provide in the constructor but it's not working the way it suppose to work. Can you please suggest something on it?

Comment: An arraylist can use a custom comperator to sort the items.

Comment: Then I would be needed to call sort method of arrayList; requirement is to not use that.